# Calling wcf webservice from node js with module or plugins

Tags: wcf, node.js

I have a requirement to call WCF dotnet webservice from node js , Can any of you suggest the best module avaiable now.

Just some references should be enough

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the WCF service has an endpoint that returns JSON you should be able to hit it with a basic node.js HTTP request.

Below is a simple sample to execute make an HTTP request from node. This should get you started. Replace "www.google.com" with the name of the server where the WCF server lives and update the path to point to the svc file:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('CHUNK: ' + chunk);
  });
  res.on('end', function () {
    console.log('DONE');
  });

});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: Thanks Hector , as it is restuful , I can pass the values in the querystring itself. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

If this is a simple service (simple xml, no advanced message level security) then I recommend to just send the raw Xml using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request).

If the xml is complex then you can use [node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap).

If there is message-level security use [wcf.js](https://github.com/yaronn/wcf.js).

Comment: basicalling its a WCF 4 webservice which has json end point , which one do you suggest for this? I am pure UI person. Webservices was there for sometime and that team told me use that. It has json end point so the response will be json from WCF 4 webservie.. its somesample.svc

Comment: so just use the node.js request module to send / receive raw json